# Scilab: write an instruction over multiple lines

Tags: scilab

Consider a file `test.sci` containing a single instruction written over two lines

```
a = 1 + 2
    + 3;
```

When executing it (File->Execute), Scilab outputs

```
a = 3
```

as if the second line had been commented out. In other words, this is what scilab sees:

```
a = 1 + 2;
//    + 3;
```

Yet, sometimes it is important for the code to remain readable to write an instruction over multiple lines. How to do this with scilab?

PS: I'm using Scilab v5.5.2 .

Answer (score 3):

An instruction can be continued on the next line using two dots `..`

```
a = 1 + 2 ..
    + 3;
```

The Matlab way i.e. putting an ellipsis `...` can also be used

```
a = 1 + 2 ...
    + 3;
```

Comment: You actually only need two (..)

Comment: Thanks @Squirrel , I've updated my answer accordingly ;)